# Как удалить строки выборочно?

Tags: python

Строки с файлов, нужно прочесть все строки с первого файла и со второго, потом посмотреть те строки которые не уникальные и удалить их
удалить строки с 1txt файла

```py
with open("textt.txt", 'r+', encoding="utf-8") as data, open('test.txt', "r+", encoding="utf8") as f:
    data_1 = data.readlines()
    data_2 = f.readlines()
    test_1 = []
    test_2 = []
    for i in data_1:
        s = i.split(' ')
        if len(s) != 12:
            del
        qs = test_1.append(i.split(' '))
        # qss = {",".join(qs)}
 
    for ii in data_2:
        qsss = test_2.append(ii.split(' '))
    asa = {','.join(test_1[0])}
    asa_1  = {','.join(test_2[0])}
    if asa.difference(asa_1) is None:
        print('asdas')
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/YPiaWsb8
мой код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну вы же понимаете, что проверить ваш код, не имея ваших исходных файлов -  невозможно.  Поэтому непонятно, что-же вы хотите от нас услышать. Если вас интересует вопрос, как выборочно удалить некоторые строки из вашего файла - то ответ однозначен

1. Читаем строки в (например) список или датафрейм.
2. Удаляем ненужные элементы из этой структуры.
3. Все что осталось -  записываем назад в
   файл.

По какому именно правилу вы будете удалять элементы во втором пункте  - это совершенно отдельный вопрос.

Если же вас интересует что-то другое -  то будте любезны, перечитайте свой вопрос и попробуйте его внятно переформулировать так, что бы он стал понятен всем.

P.S. После длительного обсуждения становиться понятным, что необходимо из одного файла удалить строки совпадающие со строками второго файла. Само чтение файла - опускаю, пусть ваши данные уже находятся в двух списках data_1 и  data_2

```
data_1=['яблоко', 'груша', 'персик','вишня']
data_2=['яблоко', 'слива', 'вишня','банан','апельсин']
set_1=set(data_1)
set_2=set(data_2)
data_3=list(set_1.difference(set_2))
print(data_3)
```

Результат:

```
['персик', 'груша']
```

Как видите, это те элементы, которые уникальны, а повторяющиеся элементы - отброшены. Вот этот список и записывайте в свой файл.

Comment: В файлах цифры, если в 1 txt который читается есть цифры такие же как и во втором, то нужно удалить эти цифры с 1 txt и перезаписать этот файл с правильными цифрами, но теперь главный вопрос, как их удалить?

Comment: Ну вы хоть читайте, что вы пишете "есть цифры такие же как и во втором, то нужно удалить эти цифры с 1 txt и перезаписать этот файл с правильными цифрами" -  так "удалить" или  "заменить на "правильные"?? Что такое "правильные цифры". Кстати, знаки препинания и разделение на предложения в русском языке вы еще в школе не проходили? Если да  - попробуйте ими воспользоваться, серьезно упрощает правильное выражение своих мыслей.  А на счет "как удалить" - ну так вы же используете метод .difference(). Или вы просто откуда-то скопировали ваш код?

Comment: в обеих файлах цифры, я должен проверить на уникальность цифры 1 txt, если какая-то из цифр совпадает с цифрой которая есть во  2 txt- удалить строку с 1 txt где находится эта цифра, насчёт кода, код сам писал

Comment: Добавил в текст сообщения.